# Bee stings vs. WebControls

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to find information about the differences (performance/usability/maintainability/readability/functionality) between using bee stings and using WebControls to render data, when using WebForms.

I am mainly focused on the `<%= %>` bee sting, which I know is equivalent to `Response.Write`. The examples below illustrate some of the scenarios that I have been considering:

**Example 1**

*Markup*

```
<span class="firstName"><%= Person.FirstName %></span>
```

vs.

*Markup*

```
<asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="firstName"></asp:Label>
```

*C#*

```
lblFirstName.Text = Person.FirstName;
```

**Example 2**

```
<input type="text" value="<%= Person.FirstName %>" data-first-name="<%= Person.FirstName %>" />
```

vs.

*Markup*

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

*C#*

```
tbFirstName.Text = Person.FirstName;
tbFirstName.Attributes.Add("data-first-name", Person.FirstName);
```

Does anyone know any major or minor differences between the two? Any insight would be greatly appreciated, but what I am really looking for is facts about the two. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The crux is that beestings are less flexible but faster.

The beestings will load the value at the very end which does not allow you to change the value if needed. The beestings are fine for example #1, but I highly recommend you do not use them for example #2

The asp.net controls have a lot of benefits for capturing user input, including preventing script injection attacks.

Comment: Very interesting - do you know any resources where I can find further information (it's okay if you do not)

Comment: I do not, but there is really not much more to it. The controls are object oriented and render the html through a series of events. Beestings are rendered directly into the output stream at the end of the page lifecycle.